# Https replaced by http on React JQuery

Tags: jquery, reactjs, https

I am trying to make a REST call from a HTTPS secured site using JQuery on React. When I enter the REST URL, JQuery seems to replace https by http and then complain that I am trying to make a HTTP request from a HTTPS secured site:

> RequestingGlobalFrom: https://www.example.com/clearerrors
>
> The page at 'https://www.example.com/getrequest/70' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.example.com/clearerrors/?user_logged=41&user_type=sometype'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Here's the code:

> ```
>   console.log('RequestingGlobalFrom: '+backend_url+"/"+entityName);
>    jQuery.ajax({url:backend_url+"/"+entityName, dataType:"json", method:'GET',
>     data:getRetrieveEntitiesData(), async: resolve!==undefined, crossDomain:true, success:(request) => {
>   console.log(entityName+' updated');
>   // The PI information is retrieved
>   let localeData = request.data;//getFilteredData(request);
>    dataStore.dispatch({type: entityName, data:localeData });
>   resolveRequest(resolve);
> ```

Can you please help me figure out what's going on?

Thank you,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry for the bother. I have already figured it out, the header

```
<meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade- 
insecure-requests"/>
```

was not present in the *index.html* file